# The number of SVDs

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

It is not hard to find the SVD for a matrix, but how to find all of them? For example, how to find how many SVDs that the identity matrix I have?

Comment: This depends a lot on the matrix. For some real matrices, there are only finitely many SVDs, and for others there are infinitely many due to arbitrary choice of basis for the relevant subspace. Do you just want an answer for $I$ or do you want all the answers? In either case, I would recommend going through the process of finding an SVD and keeping track of all of the steps where you can make a choice.

Comment: I want to know how to find that for all the real matrices. I think if someone can use identity matrix as an example, it would make the process more clear.

Comment: The way I usually do it is to find a set of linearly independent vectors to start as $v_1, v_2$ and so on.. so I am not sure how to find them all. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Usually one would start with $A^TA$... I'm having trouble finding an online source that is clear enough about the general algorithm to serve as a reference. There is some introductory explanation at [MIT Open Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/singular-value-decomposition/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.5sum.pdf) but it's not actually enough to make all of the cases clear.

Comment: If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $AIA^T$ is a valid SVD form of the identity matrix. Clearly, there are $n(n-1)/2$ orthogonal matrices where $n$ is the dimension of space. For a general matrix, the only thing I know there are at least $n(n-1)/2$ SVD forms.

Comment: How do you guys approach questions like these? For me, for example, if I am about to find a SVD for a 2x2 matrix. I'll set $v_1$ to be $(1, 0)^T$ and $v_2$ to be the transpose of $(0,1)$. Since $Av_1= s_1u_1$, it is pretty convenient.

Comment: @Syuizen Where do you get that? Is it a theorem that one can use directly without proving it? And that means for the identity matrix and all the other 2 by 2 matrix, there is only 1 SVD, correct?

Comment: The number of @Syuizen is the dimension of the orthogonal group. Every matrix of that continuum is a valid candidate. Note that the SVD of a matrix $A$ is equivalent to the eigen-decomposition of  the symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{0&A\\A^T&0}$ so that you can translate the full spectral theory of symmetric matrices.